# Google Sheets - Concatenate 2 rows across columns into 1 cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to achieve what's in the Desired Output column in the image below. I need to take what's in row 1 (id1, id2, etc.), add ":" to that, then concatenate it with the values under each of the Field columns, add "|" to each ID-Value pair, and get that all together into one cell. I need the formula to also work for empty cells, as the number of fields to concatenate together is dynamic.

So far I've tried a big CONCATENATE formula in one cell, but I can only get it to work for as many non-blank cells as I include in the formula.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Can you add an example of what you expect when there are empty cells too?  What formula are you currently using?

Comment: Excel? Or Google Sheets? Why use the wrong tags?

Comment: This is for Google Sheets, my apologies. I figured that there might be a formula that worked for both but maybe not.

Comment: @BruceWayne I'm literally just concatenating and it's not going to work dynamically. For empties, I don't want to include the ":" and "|" characters. FWIW, this is my concatenate:
=CONCATENATE($D$1, ":", D3, "|", $E$1, ":", E3, "|", $F$1, ":", F3, "|", $G$1, ":", G3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets)

Use JOIN:

```
=arrayformula(join("|",filter($B$1:$E$1& ":" & B2:E2,B2:E2<>"")))
```

[image]

---

[excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula)

Use TEXTJOIN

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",,IF(B2:E2<>"",$B$1:$E$1 & ":" & B2:E2,""))
```

This will be an array formula and must be confirmed with ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Hey, this is awesome! There's one thing I'm still struggling with. I need the formula to work up to e.g. column H. I need to check if the ID row (row 1) cell is empty, and if it is empty, I don't want to include ":" and "|" - does that make sense?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about when stretching it a few more columns:

id1:Val 1|id2:Val 2|id3:Val 3|id4:Val 4|:|:

Comment: I suppose I could just do a substitute on the "|:" string with empty? But that's a little hacky

Comment: I accepted the answer but I'm now realizing that I need to have something else that checks the Value fields and if they're blank, I want to leave the e.g. ID1: part off.

So if we took out Oval3 in Row 4 Col D, it'd be: ID1:Oval 1|ID2:Oval 2|ID4:Oval 4

Comment: In Excel this is easy, but in Google I will need to look further into it, I can leave it blank so you end up with `||` instead of the single.

Comment: Ah gotcha, is there anything specific I can look up? How would you do it in Excel? Maybe I can see how that might translate to Sheets. Also, instead of a double "||", maybe a different character that I can sub out from the whole string. Thanks, Scott!

Comment: It will not translate as TEXTJOIN has the ability to ignore blanks while JOIN on sheets does not.  So Filter may need to be involved.  I am in a meeting and cannot test.  If I get time later I will post an update.

Comment: Wow, this is absolutely perfect. Thank you, Scott!